# How do I add subscript to a stargazer table covariate label?

Tags: label, subscript, stargazer

Within the below covariate labels I'd like to include P, M and C in subscript. Here is my code:

```
   stargazer(DD1_PT, DD1_MT, DD1_CT,
          type = "text", 
          title = "Table 1", 
          out = "table1.html", 
          dep.var.labels.include = FALSE, 
          column.labels = c("Presidential", "Midterm", "Constitutional"), 
          model.numbers = FALSE, 
          order=c(4, 1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 10, 5, 6, 7),   
          covariate.labels=c("TimeP (1 = 2016/0 = 2012)","TimeP*Vote center", "TimeM (1 = 2018/0 
          = 2010)", "TimeM*Vote center", "TimeC (1 = 2017/0 = 2009)", "TimeC*Vote center"), 
          no.space=TRUE, 
          omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f"), 
          notes = c("Standard errors given in parentheses ", "Population scaled to 1,000,000 and 
          income scaled to 10,000"), 
          notes.align = "r"))
```

Any ideas as to how I do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the `type = "text"`. It will be difficult to make subscripted characters in plain text.

If you set your output to `html`, then you can just use `stringr::str_replace()` to put in the HTML for a subscript: `<sub> <\sub>`.

For a reproducible example, let's use `mtcars`:

Imagine that we want to make the last letter of "Observations" subscripted in the table.

```
library(stargazer)
library(tidyverse)

fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
output <- stargazer(fit1, type = "HTML") # gives you output

# replace output with the subscripted html
output <- str_replace(output, "Observations", "Observation<sub>s</sub>")

write_lines(output, "subscript_example.html")
```

which gives the desired subscript, as below:

[image]

As a final note, I have read that it is better to edit HTML using `xml2` rather than `str_replace()`. Perhaps someone else can help with that. The above solution does work for me.